# How can I set a custom quote character/no quote character when exporting to CSV using JOOQ?

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, jooq

**Update**:
This is not supported (yet). I've filed a [ticket](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3330) after talking to the creator of JOOQ.

---

I'm referring to the `formatCSV()` method. Something like this:

```
DSLContext create = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.MYSQL);
String csv = create.selectFrom(BOOK).fetch().formatCSV('\t');
```

The [documentation](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.3/manual-single-page/#exporting-csv) mentions a way to specify a custom representation for `NULL` values but says nothing about quote character AFAIK.

Comment: I've added your issue as an answer to this question to help future visitors understand how this was resolved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said yourself in your updated question, this is not yet supported in jOOQ 3.3. The relevant issue is [issue #3330](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3330)